# How to put fixedbanners at margin of website

Tags: wordpress

everyone.i been currently using wordpress for my website and my request is how i can put fixed banners outside the margin on left and right side i.e the banners should be placed in white spaces available beside left and right margin and also they should be fixed when scrolled.

if anyone please do know this can tell me so that i would be happy to use the same at my website

Comment: Questions regarding [coding](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and design are considered off-topic for this site. For WordPress related questions, you might ask next time on our [WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site, or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) if just about coding.

Answer (score 0):

i myself has found the answer on web.so can close this

need to include this stylesheet

/* Begin Floating Ads Style */

## float-left {

position:fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 980px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  border-bottom: solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

#float-right {
  position:fixed;
  top: 5px;
  right:10px;
  bottom: 5px;
  float:right;
  width: 125px;
  height: 980px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  border-bottom: solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
/* End Floating Ads Style */

and in header file

above body tag include this code

adcode



adcode

above adcode must be replaced with respective code

Comment: one of code i display not appearing in text

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer this yourself, unfortunately it's off-topic for this particular site (see the above comment), but feel free to ask and answer other questions [on-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here in the future.